# statement.executeQuery) not working in NetBeans java

Tags: java, netbeans

I am trying to output the first column (nameID) of my table (StudentInfo) in my database. But the statement.executeQuery is not working and ResultSet.next() is false.

- Java NetBeans program
- Calls sqlite database
- Uses "jdbc:sqlite:ProjectWeekDB.sqlite" as url

```java
    private static Connection connection = null;
    private static PreparedStatement stmt = null;
    private static Statement statement = null;
    private static ResultSet results = null;

    public static void createNewDatabase() {
        String sqlData = "SELECT * FROM StudentInfo";
        String url;
        try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
            if (connection != null) {
                statement = connection.createStatement();
                stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sqlData);
                statement.executeUpdate(sqlData);
                results = statement.executeQuery(sqlData);
                while (results.next()) {
                   print(results.getInt("nameID"));
                }
                stmt.close();
                results.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            print(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       createNewDatabase();
    }
```

It just prints out BUILD successful without actually displaying the first column in the database.

Comment: How are you running the application.

Comment: why do you do `statement.executeUpdate(sqlData);` ?

Comment: Have you try to debug the project? Do you know the connection is successfully established or not?

Comment: -I am running the application on NetBeans java

Comment: I have debugged....yes, the connection is successful

Comment: Good, While debugging step by step are you facing any exception if yes then in which line it throws an exception? and also have you register your driver or write something like `Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");` before `DriverManager.getConnection`

Comment: I wasn't sure whether to use Statement or PreparedStatement as both are giving the same output on the console...build successful

Comment: Class.forName doesn't change anything :(